# IF condition doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, if-statement

I would like to write a query using `IF`, but its not working , what's wrong with this query?

```
SELECT
IF(Emp.Name is not null)     
        ((Emp.Name) + '_' + (Emp.LastName)) as ID
else
   Emp.ID
```

I get this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
```

Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: SQL has no `IF`. Tell us what you're trying to do. Add sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: The syntax is `SELECT IF(condition,iftrue,iffalse) AS colname` [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN emp.name is not null THEN emp.name + '_' + emp.lastName 
            ELSE Emp.id 
       END as [ID]
FROM ...
```

The `IF()` is performed differently in SQL-Server (I assume by the concat syntax),

```
IF ( Condition ) 
    SQL STATEMENT
ELSE
    SQL STATEMENT
```

Which means you need to perform the entire select in each block. Your kind of `IF()` is used in MySQL , `IF(Condition , THEN , ELSE )`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this in a `CASE` clause:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (Emp.Name IS NOT NULL)     
    THEN ((Emp.Name) + '_' + (Emp.LastName)) 
ELSE
Emp.ID
END as ID
```

The `IF..ELSE` syntax is somewhat different:

```
IF(Emp.Name IS NOT NULL)    
   SELECT ((Emp.Name) + '_' + (Emp.LastName)) AS ID
ELSE
   SELECT Emp.ID AS ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using Case in your query check this [MySQL: CASE Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/case.php)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's SQL Server based on your syntax use this:

```
SELECT CASE <variable> WHEN <value>      THEN <returnvalue>
                       WHEN <othervalue> THEN <returnthis>
                                         ELSE <returndefaultcase>
   END AS <newcolumnname> 
FROM <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of usinf IF, you can use CASE in SELECT statement. Something like this

```
SELECT
  CASE Emp.Name
    WHEN NULL THEN Emp.ID
    ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(Emp.Name,'_'),Emp.LastName)
    END AS "ID"
FROM Emp;
```

Hope it helps.